# Opening .spo SPSS file in R

Tags: r, spss

I am just wondering if I can read a .spo SPSS output file in R? I have tried the foreign package but it won't allow me to read .spo files. Does anyone know if there any other way of reading this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those .spo files are output files generated by SPSS. They might contain code, tables and graphics.

I'm not aware of any R package that might open them. However, the open source SPSS clone PSPP (http://www.gnu.org/software/pspp/) does usually open them. There also used to exist an SPSS Legacy Viewer software that allowed one to view the contents of these output files.

With pure R you might be out of luck.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I thought so thats the case but just wanted to confirm. regards,Ayan

Answer (score 1):

It seems that "PSPP cannot read SPSS output files (though it can read SPSS
data and syntax files)."

http://osdir.com/ml/pspp-users-gnu/2009-12/msg00008.html